# Why won't my .s file assemble using my Raspberry Pi VM?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, gnu

I created a virtual machine using [this version of raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop). I am trying to assemble the simple assembly program "program.s"

```
.global _start
_start: 
        mov    r0,#0 @ exit status code 0 for normal completion
        mov    r7,#1 @ service command 1 terminates this program
        svc    0     @ issue linux command to terminate program
```

Assembling with

```
as -o program.o program.s
```

gives

```
GNU assembler version 2.28 (i686-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils 
for Debian) 2.28
e.s: Assembler messages:
e.s:6: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
e.s:7: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
e.s:8: Error: no such instruction: `svc 0'
```

I don't think the issue is with the code, rather it has something to do with the type of assembly the assembler is trying to assemble. I'm a total beginner to the Raspberry Pi and to assembly in general so I'm completely at a loss for a solution.

Comment: Where do you assemble your code? It looks like you assemble it on an i386 system instead of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: That raspberry pi vm looks like it's for x86 processors, so you can't assemble ARM code on it (at least not with the default compiler toolchain)

Comment: `#` is the comment character for x86 GAS synatx.  That's why the assembler "got nothing" after the comma.